# Regex expression to match all instances of string

Tags: c#, regex

Using System.Text.RegularExpressions with the following expression to match all tokens wrapped with # that contain only text (no whitespace etc)

```
#([a-zA-Z]+)#
```

and the following test string

```
text #test# text #test1# text
```

I only get one match. What am I doing wrong in my regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) method, which returns a collection of all matches.

Also, A-Z is not really a good solution for text (and indeed the 1 in `#test1#` will not be matched!!!), since it doesn't include any extended character, such as éàèöäü etc. - you may want to look at `\w` which matches word characters, or `\p{L}` to match any letter in any language.

Edit: maybe this would suit your needs better:

```
#([^\s#]+)#
```

Answer (score 2):

It will match the first item only

use `NextMatch()` function